# Task Failed With Error In Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I create an mobile application in xamarin.forms and It works proper but now I connect to **appCenter** for virtual builder and appcenter give me a below error.

### [error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5_4_1/bin/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.

If anyone have !dea about above error please help me.
I am new here and I am not aware about how to ask question for different subject please help me.

In my app mostly create for the ios application so give IOS as a priority.

Comment: Have you created project in vs2017 or vs2017 for mac?

Comment: I created project in vs17 but now I need to use mac.

Comment: So, are you connecting mac or configure your project in mac?

Comment: Actually I am using git that's why in which system I have to use project at that time I am clone from the server. And In mac system I also clone but not working properly.

Comment: I have no idea about mac. But you can try connecting mac with your windows and build your app using windows.

Comment: But I have no more windows system that's why I am using mac system and further development process is done on mac system with Visual studio for mac..

Comment: Okay. Try to clean and build solution once again.